# capture the min effective dated record from a max term record

Tags: sql

I'm having a difficult time trying to capture the oldest/min record after the max eff dated term record.

Example:

```
Status    Date
Active    8-1-2013
Active    7-2-2013
Active    6-1-2012****this is the date I need
Term      5-30-2012
Active    4-12-2012
Term      3-5-2012
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Considering that `4-12-2012` is less than `6-1-2012` in the `Active` group, what logic are you using to determine that `6-1-2012` is the minimum here?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you explain?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I get the impression that what's desired is the earliest date, from a record with Active status, which falls after the latest date, from a record with Term status.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO . . . It is the oldest record *after* the last term.  The last term is 2012-05-30, so the highlighted record is the correct one according to that statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly,

```
 select min(Date) from table where status = 'Active' and Date >
 (select max(Date) from table where Status = 'Term')
```

Comment: thank you!  The code above works! Do you know how to add an else statement where if there is no term record then get the min of the first active record?  Active only records are dropping off of my dataset.

Comment: @user2438137, use a dummy start date for that case, like so, `select min(Date) from table where status = 'Active' and Date > isnull(
 (select max(Date) from table where Status = 'Term'), '19000101')`

Comment: It almost worked. I am able to capture all active records that do not have a term date but I lose the correct active record date from my original request above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is syntax that works in MySQL:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date > (select MAX(t.date) from t where status = 'TERM')
order by date
limit 1;
```

In other databases, the `limit 1` might be `select top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or even something else.

If you just want the date, then you can use 1_CR's solution.